# Where cygwin stores Unix file attributes

Tags: cygwin

Where does Cygwin stores Unix-specific file attributes, e.g. the executable flag? Is it possible to read them with non-Cygwin applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original file attributes are being translated into unix file attributes depending on the oriinal filesystem. Have a look at this explanation: http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-filemodes.html